# Iterate and match in large files in python

Tags: python, performance, algorithm, python-3.x

I have two large text files:

’letters’ with > 600 000 lines

’numbers’ with > 100 000 lines

letters looks like this:

```
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
etc…
```

numbers have two columns, one ’id’ and one with a list of numbers:

```
    id1 5, 201, 66, 33
    id2 356
    id3 5103, 2, 452
    etc…
```

I want each row in ’letters’ to represent a number:

```
    1   AAAA
    2    AAAB
    etc…
```

and then check what row in ’numbers’ contains that number, then pair that id with the combination of letters, in this case only:

```
AAAB    id3
```

This script takes days to run:

```
combine = {}
for i, x in enumerate(letters):
    for id, number in numbers.items():
        if i+1 in number:
            combine[x['letter']] = id
```

Is there a faster way to do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1e5 and 6e5 are not large numbers if you use a linear time algorithm instead of the quadratic one:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
with open('letters') as file:
    letters = file.read().splitlines()

def combine_ids(letters):
    with open('numbers') as file:
        for line in file:
            id, space, numbers_str = line.lstrip().partition(' ')
            try:
                numbers = list(map(int, numbers_str.split(',')))
            except ValueError:
                continue # skip invalid lines
            for n in numbers:
                try:
                    yield letters[n], id
                except IndexError:
                    pass

result = dict(combine_ids(letters))
print(result)
```

If multiple ids may correspond to the same letter (if there are duplicate numbers in `numbers` file) then the latest number wins.

#### Example

numbers:

```
id1 5, 33
id2 23
id3 103, 2, 3
```

letters:

```
AAAA
AAAB
AAAC
AAAD
AAAE
AAAF
AAAG
AAAH
AAAI
AAAJ
AAAK
...
AAAX
AAAY
AAAZ
```

#### Output

```
{'AAAX': 'id2', 'AAAC': 'id3', 'AAAD': 'id3', 'AAAF': 'id1'}
```

Note: the number `2` corresponds to `AAAC` here (zero-based indexing), use `letters[n-1]` if letters should be indexed from `1` (assuming `n>=1`).

Comment: Looks exactly right! But it seems like 'line' in number file doesn't make a new line, but instead writes '\r'. Any thought on how I get around this?: b'ID1 41820,91535,153900,191776,277339\rID2 8,181055,235156,242726,293493,305121\rID3 11,4,29\rID4 16,17\rID5 19,20,2,3,24'

Comment: @user3575737: if your file uses `'\r'` as a newline (old Mac) then open the file in text mode to enable universal newlines mode. Change the code to use ordinary str literals in this case. I've updated the answer.

Comment: Wouldn't `(l for l in file)` be nicer than`file.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @Evpok: no. `letters` should be a sequence here but `()` creates a generator expression.

Comment: Oh, indeed, I forgot that you needed a sequence.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a single pass over each file, O(N):

1. Read letters file into array. You will get array index (+ 1?) = Line number.
2. Read numbers file. For each row: Use the numbers to combine `id` with letters from array.

Comment: Thank you for your input. Since the letters file contains far more lines than numbers, this is the list I must iterate through in order to cover each item..

Comment: What do you mean? If a number is missing you can't find it using your method either (since it isn't there). If it is there, it will be used to combine letters with an id.

Comment: The way it works now, I go through each row in 'letters' and look for each row number among the numbers in the 'numbers' list (which can be hundreds per id). If I find a match, for example if AAAA is on row 1 and number one is found on the row where id3 is, AAAA = id3. If instead I would loop for each row in the numbers file this will only cover 1/6 of the letters, since I have 100k numbers rows and 600k letters rows.

Comment: There are several numbers on each row. If there is an average of 6 numbers on each row you have 600k numbers.

Answer (score 1):

Store all letters in a list `letters = ["AAAA", "AAAB", "AAAC", ...]`.

Now after reading in the numbers file create a mapping like

```
0 mapped to id1
1 mapped to id2
....

m[0] = "id1", m[1] = "id2"...
```

While doing the above step, create a array of zeroes, read in the numbers file and assign the row to which mapping it belongs

```
p = [0] * len(letters)
nums = row[row.find(" ") + 1:].split(", ")
row_name = row[:row.find(" ") - 1]
for num in nums:
    p[num] = m[row_name]
```

Now for finding the ith letter in `letters` list and its number just do

```
print p[i]
```